# double Gtk::Messadialog before quitting

Tags: c++, gtk, gtkmm

I'm trying to display a message dialog if the pid of running program is valid, This is my essencial code:

```
Gtk::Main kit (argc, argv);
Glib::RefPtr<Gtk::Builder> refBuilder = Gtk::Builder::create();
try { refBuilder->add_from_file (UI_PATH); }
catch (const Glib::FileError& ex) {
    std::cout << "FileError: " << ex.what() << std::endl;
    return 1;
}
catch (const Gtk::BuilderError& ex) {
    std::cout << "BuilderError: " << ex.what() << std::endl;
    return 1;
}
FormUI * ui = 0;
refBuilder->get_widget_derived ("window1", ui);
if (ui) {
    kit.run (*ui);
}
delete ui;
```

Constructor:

```
signal_delete_event ().connect (sigc::mem_fun (*this, &FormUI::on_delete_event));
```

method:

```
    bool FormUI::on_delete_event (GdkEventAny* event) {
if (_pid) {
    bool retState;
    Gtk::MessageDialog md(*this, Glib::ustring::compose ("<b>%1</b>", _("Warning: youtube-dl in process")), true, Gtk::MESSAGE_WARNING, Gtk::BUTTONS_YES_NO, true);
    md.set_title (PACKAGE_STRING);
    md.set_secondary_text (_("Closing can generate a corrupted file, do you want to continue anyway?"));
    if (md.run() == Gtk::RESPONSE_YES) {
        kill (_pid, 0);
        retState = false;
    } else {
        retState = true;
    }
    md.hide ();
    return retState;
}
return false;
```

}

With the above, if pid is valid it displays the messagedialog as expected, but if I hit "yes" (to exit the application) it displays another messagedialog..why?

Comment: What happens if you rename your `on_delete_event()` method? (If this works, wait for the answer; it will have the explanation. Or you can try deducing it from the rest of this comment.) And is `FormUI` derived from `Gtk::Window`? I'm assuming it is from your `refBuilder->get_widget_derived()` call, but I want to be sure.

Comment: Wow, I renamed the delete handler to cb_on_delete_event and it works as expected: only one messagedialog. Yes, FormUI is derived from Gtk::Window, which came from builder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You said that `FormUI` is derived from `Gtk::Window`. `Gtk::Window` has [a virtual method `on_delete_event()`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm/stable/classGtk_1_1Widget.html#aa97a4453ec12f7fce163353c2bcaf580) that is automatically connected to the `delete-event` signal, no questions asked. Oops, you implemented a virtual method without knowing it! So what you did by calling

```
signal_delete_event ().connect (sigc::mem_fun (*this, &FormUI::on_delete_event));
```

was unknowingly connect that signal twice, and because `Gtk::Window::on_delete_event()` is virtual, both connections go to your own method.

Okay, so why do we still get two dialog boxes? Doesn't returning `false` mean to close the window? Not really.

`delete-event` is a GDK event. GDK events always return a boolean value: if the value is `false` (`GDK_EVENT_PROPAGATE`), the next signal handler in the signal connection chain is run, and if the return value is `true` (`GDK_EVENT_STOP`), no further signal in the signal connection chain is run.

It just so happens that if you don't stop a `delete-event` from propagating through the signal connection chain, the window is destroyed. So when there was only one handler connected, returning `false` from that handler would *effectively* destroy the window.

But now you have two handlers connected. The first one will return `false`, which causes the second one to run, and you get your second message dialog. When that one returns `false`, you get your window being destroyed.

Hopefully that should explain this problem. You can solve this by either not calling `signal_delete_event().connect()` or by changing the method name to something else. Be sure to watch the gtkmm documentation to make sure you aren't accidentally using other virtual methods that are automatically connected to signals (I'm not sure why gtkmm provides these virtual methods; convenience?). And be sure to understand how GDK events work; you'll need to know this if you ever play with GDK events for real (such as handling input in a `Gtk::DrawingArea`).

Comment: Oh, man! Thanks for the info, really really helped...so I just need to not to use same virtual methods names in my class.